# Not able to download the folder having excel file by zipping it in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, zip

In Rshiny application, I am using zip from the utils package and trying to download a zip using the downloadHandler.

So, I can download a folder having csv, images in it by zipping but when I am trying to download a folder having a workbook (excel) file in it by zipping, it's giving me following error:

```
Warning: Error in path.expand: invalid 'path' argument
[No stack trace available]
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
temporary_directory <- tempdir()

    #ZIP purpose directory creation
output_directory <-
  paste("network_data_bundle", gsub("[ :]", "_", Sys.time()), sep = "_")

network_data_bundle_path <-
  paste(temporary_directory, output_directory, sep = "/")

## Create a new workbook
wb <- createWorkbook("temp_wrokbook")

#************* START: ADDING INSTRUCTION SHEET ************#
# adding instructions worksheet to the workbook
addWorksheet(wb, CONSTANT_MM_WORKBOOK_SHEET_INSTRUCTION, gridLines = TRUE) 

# loading instructions sheet workbook
instructions_wb <- loadWorkbook(CONSTANT_MM_WORKBOOK_INSTRUCTION_FILE_NAME)

wb <- copyWorkbook(instructions_wb)

temp_mm_data_file <- paste(network_data_bundle_path, "test1.xlsx", sep = "/")

saveWorkbook(wb, temp_mm_data_file, overwrite = TRUE)



# set working directory as tem directory for zip purpose
setwd(temporary_directory)

# zip all the files and sub-directories
zip(zipfile = filename,
    files = paste(output_directory, "/", sep = ""))
```

I have already spent more than couple of hours but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: It's unclear which line is causing the error, can you clarify? If you're downloading a web file, sometimes you need to download the file in a separate statement first, depending on the function.

Comment: Also double check that your constructed paths are valid

Comment: @Mako212 the paths I have constructed are valid. The same things works for downloading the csv or images. The last line, i.e zip function is causing an error.